# IV Parameter must be as long as the block size, but encryption/decryption still works

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I am trying to write a simple 2 way encryption class using mcrypt to learn more about encryption, and everything seems to be working fine. The issue that I am having is I am receiving a PHP error stating "IV parameter must be as long as the block size" however, the encryption and decryption both seem to be working. Is my understanding of IV size incorrect? Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit: I am actually wrong, the encryption/decryption is not working and I am unsure why.**

**Edit2: Alright, I figured out why the encryption wasn't working (thanks to Robert) but the original problem still exists.**

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

class IDBCrypt {

    private $iv_size, $hash_type, $hash_size, $hash_key, $encryption_key;

    const SECRET_KEY = "Ep8+NFPfybsJn26ZFyPn213WTI";
    const HASH_KEY = "mU2YjBiZDVmYjBiOWUyNmE";
    const HASH_TYPE = "sha256";
    const HASH_SIZE = 64;

    /** 
      * For SHA256 hashing algorithm
      * each digit requires 4 bits of
      * memory. This means that you need
      * 64 digits to represent a 256 bit 
      * hash, thereby making the size of 
      * a hash generated with this algorithm
      * 256 bits, with a length of 64
      */

    function __construct() {

        /* Constructor */

    }

    function encrypt( $data ) {

        // Generate an IV to encrypt with
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv( self::HASH_SIZE, MCRYPT_RAND );
        $hashed_iv = hash_hmac( self::HASH_TYPE, $iv, self::HASH_KEY );

        // echo $iv ."<br><br>";

        // Encrypt plain text
        $cipher_text = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::SECRET_KEY, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $hashed_iv );

        // Base64 encode and salt the data
        $cipher_text_64 = base64_encode( $hashed_iv . $cipher_text );

        return $cipher_text_64;

    }

    function decrypt( $data ) {

        // Base64 decode the cipher text
        $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode( $data );

        // retrieves the IV/salt from the cipher text
        $iv_dec = substr( $ciphertext_dec, 0, self::HASH_SIZE );

        // retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
        $ciphertext_dec = substr( $ciphertext_dec, self::HASH_SIZE );

        $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::SECRET_KEY, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec );

        return $plaintext;

    }

}

$crypt = new IDBCrypt();

$string = $crypt->encrypt("Greetings from encryption and beyond");

echo $string . "<br>";

echo $crypt->decrypt($string);

?>
```

Comment: You should definitly check `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size() `function

Comment: where do u set 'iv_size' i can't find it?

Comment: Thanks for that catch, I was going crazy trying to figure out why the encryption broke. Now that the encryption is working, I'm still getting the original error "The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize". I've edited the code to reflect that fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in `mcrypt_function()`

You pass hashed IV instead of IV created by `mcrypt_create_iv()` that is why size is different.

You can get proper IV size with function `mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 , 'cbc');`

The proper length of IV is 16 bytes for RIJNDAEL 128(other mode than ECB, ECB doesn't use IV).

So you can change(because you passed 64)

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv( self::HASH_SIZE, MCRYPT_RAND );
```

to

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv( 16, MCRYPT_RAND );
```

And it will work.

Edit:

Check this simple example. Of course padding needs to be removed

```
$text ='asdf';
$key = 'Ep8+NFPfybsJn26ZFyPn213WTI';
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv( 16, MCRYPT_RAND );
$cipher_text = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $cipher_text , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. So for the sake of testing I ditched the hashed iv and used the normally generated IV using mcrypt_create_iv(). Then I used mcrypt_get_iv_size() to generate the size of the IV which is 16 in this case. When I do all of this, the encryption still works however I still receive that same warning message.

Comment: @L337Man Your key is only 26 characters long. It needs to be either 16, 24 or 32 bytes long.

Comment: 16 bytes for RIJANDEL 128

Comment: @Artjom B Oh ok, let me give that a go.  Can you explain to me why that is (or provide a link), or is it just defined by php?

Comment: @Robert what if I used RIJANDEL 256?

Comment: @L337Man No, this is how AES and Rijndael are specified which all implementations of those algorithms should honor.

Comment: Then it would be 32 bytes long.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Is it just a standards kind of thing, because changing the length of the key didn't affect the encryption, and it also didn't make the warning go away.

Comment: AES = Rijandel :) AES is standard and Rijandel is name of algortihm that AES uses.

Comment: Oh alright, I got it. Jeez there's a lot to know about this stuff. What exactly in my code is causing that warning, if I might ask. I changed the code to use 16 when creating the IV and it didn't cause the warning to disappear, however your simple example worked without a warning.

Comment: @Robert *AES = Rijandel* is not entirely correct. Rijndael with a block size of 128 bit is the same as AES. Both support the same three key sizes.